# How to restrict a generic type in a vector so that it can be converted to f32?

Tags: generics, rust, types, typing

How can I make sure that the following function works for both integers and floats?

```
fn mean<T>(data: &Vec<T>) -> f32 {
    let sum = data.iter().sum::<T>() as f32;
    let count = data.len();
    return sum / count as f32;
}
```

I'm guessing I'd need to use some sort of bound or where clause to solve this, but I'm not sure about the syntax.

I've tried what the compiler suggests:

```
fn mean<T: std::iter::Sum<&T>>(data: &Vec<T>) -> f32 {...}
```

but I still get an error saying `'explicit lifetime name needed'`.

I feel I'm missing something obvious here.
Is there a way for instance to restrict `T` to types that can be cast to `f32`?
If yes, that would (I assume) also satisfy the `sum()` function.

Comment: Nitpick: `&Vec` is an antipattern. Use `&[T]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I assume that this is your current code:

```rust
fn mean<'a, T>(data: &'a [T]) -> f32
where
    T: std::iter::Sum<&'a T>,
{
    let sum = data.iter().sum::<T>() as f32;
    let count = data.len();
    return sum / count as f32;
}
```

Here the compiler correctly complains about the fact that `T` cannot be converted to an `f32`, because the `where` clause does not include that `T` has such a capability.

Sadly, there is no trait for *"coercible to `f32`"*, as the `as` operator is a built-in operation.

---

You could, as you mentioned, use the `From`/`Into` traits to implement this function for every type that can be converted into an f32 via `.into()`:

```rust
fn mean<'a, T>(data: &'a [T]) -> f32
where
    T: std::iter::Sum<&'a T> + Into<f32>,
{
    let sum = data.iter().sum::<T>().into();
    let count = data.len();
    return sum / count as f32;
}

fn main() {
    let v = vec![1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0];
    println!("{}", mean(&v));
    let v2: Vec<i16> = vec![1, 2, 3, 4];
    println!("{}", mean(&v2));
}
```

```
2.5
2.5
```

Note, however, that `Into<f32>` is [*not* implemented for all numeric types](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.From.html).
For example, it is *not* implemented for `i32`, as `i32` cannot be converted to an `f32` without losing information.

---

If you still want to use any primitive type that can be converted to an `f32` even if there are losses, you will have to use an external crate like the excellent [`num-traits`](https://crates.io/crates/num-traits). From it, you could use the [`AsPrimitive<f32>`](https://docs.rs/num-traits/latest/num_traits/cast/trait.AsPrimitive.html) trait:

```rust
fn mean<'a, T>(data: &'a [T]) -> f32
where
    T: std::iter::Sum<&'a T> + num_traits::AsPrimitive<f32>,
{
    let sum = data.iter().sum::<T>().as_();
    let count = data.len();
    return sum / count as f32;
}

fn main() {
    let v = vec![1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0];
    println!("{}", mean(&v));
    let v2: Vec<i32> = vec![1, 2, 3, 4];
    println!("{}", mean(&v2));
}
```

```
2.5
2.5
```

Comment: Thanks! This works. (nice tip about the num-traits crate)

Answer (score 1):

If you follow the suggestions from the compiler further, you should arrive at something like `<'a, T: 'a + Sum<&T>>`.

Then you notice that you can't use `as` because there's no trait for it. Substitute `Into`: `let sum: f32 = data.iter().sum::<T>().into();`

Some more compiler suggestions and you should arrive at: `fn mean<'a, T: 'a + std::iter::Sum<&'a T>>(data: &'a Vec<T>) -> f32 where f32: From<T>`.

Comment: This helped, however, now I'm getting an error in the call site: `the trait From<i32> is not implemented for f32`. Maybe I'm not calling it correctly. Let's say I have a vector `data: Vec<i32>` how would I call the `mean` function? (these don't seem to work: `mean<i32>(data)` or `mean::<i32>(data)`.

Comment: Hm, that's true, not everything that can be `as`ed can be `into`'d. I'm not sure what the best course of action is here. You could use `TryInto`, but that would make your function fallible. You could use `cast` from the `num_traits` crate. (I think. I haven't tried.) Or you [could](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=564b4de546b79794b432e8e61535bacc) put the responsibility onto the caller by taking an `impl Iterator<Item = f32>`

Comment: @Caesar [`AsPrimitive`](https://docs.rs/num/latest/num/cast/trait.AsPrimitive.html) is a direct replacement to `as`.